# error of Material list of angular components in angular dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

Whenever I am trying to populate a list of item with `material-list` in a `display: inline-flex;` the flex doesn't responses, the list only gets align horizontally, but if I change the HTML code from `material-list` to `ul` it populates the list as expected. So, can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

[image]
list.html

```
    <div class="demo-list-content">
     <material-list>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="home"></material-icon>
            <div class="demo-list-item">Item 1</div>
        </material-list-item>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="home"></material-icon>
            <div class="demo-list-item">Item 1</div>
        </material-list-item>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="home"></material-icon>
            <div class="demo-list-item">Item 1</div>
        </material-list-item>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="home"></material-icon>
            <div class="demo-list-item">Item 1</div>
        </material-list-item>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="home"></material-icon>
            <div class="demo-list-item">Item 1</div>
        </material-list-item>
    </material-list>
</div>
```

list.css

```
.demo-list-content {
    margin: 24px;
}

material-list {
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

material-list-item {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: solid;
    margin: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.demo-list-item {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the flex related stuff and add the following style it should wrap

```
.material-list-item {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for understanding the question and help.